# Centering Two Side-by-side ImageViews

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-xml

I want to center two image views, but I couldn't get it working. Currently I have:

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
        android:src="@drawable/tw" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
        android:src="@drawable/fb" />
```

Any suggestions on what I have to add to make it both centered?

This is what I wanted to achieve, where I could set a specific margin from the bottom:
[image: This is what I wanted to achieve]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:background="@drawable/red_android_background"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/somevalue">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
                    android:src="@drawable/tw" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:onClick="goToMainMenu"
                    android:src="@drawable/fb" />
        </LinearLayout
</RelativeLayout>
```

You might need to add a weight attribute of 1 for both `ImageView`s if they are different sizes.

Answer (score 2):

Its simple.

Take `RelativeLayout` as your root layout. Then, just wrap these two images in a `LinearLayout` (Horizontal) and simply assign property `CenterInParent` to `LinearLayout`. And you will achieve what you want.

Comment: I tried this and wrapped them in a LinearLayout but I get the FB and TW images upwards not side-to-side. What code should I put to make it side-to-side?

Comment: Okay, saw it in the other answer. it's just the `android:orientation="horizontal"` ... :)